# python android webview sl4a

Tags: android, python, webview

I have a problem with webviews. I would like to use two webviews in one python script. Is it possible? I tried it, but i get some problem.

As a know  i can show a webview with the following command:

```
`droid.webViewShow('file:///sdcard/sl4a/scripts/1.html')`
```

After that, 1.html is appearing on my phone screen. It is OK. Now, i would like to change it to another html with the command webviewshow.

```
`droid.webViewShow('file:///sdcard/sl4a/scripts/2.html')`
```

2.html appear on my phone screen. But when i close my script, 1.html is still appearing on my phone screen, with all the options menu items that I add to it, but the menu items don't responding anything.

Is there any solution to close all webviews?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try droid.dismiss() to close every web view

Answer (score 0):

Use droid.dismiss() as pointed by Tamas but from inside the HTML code.

Like this:

```
 <button id="killer" type="button"
       onclick="droid.eventPost('kill', ''); droid.dismiss()"
 >KILL BUTTON</button>
```